# Need to Send Email from HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html

I m creating a Website as Static HTML pages. In that only in one contacts page alone i need to get the users  name and emailId .  This information should be send to a particular mail Id with the information of username and emailId.

I m using only HTML and Javascript , can anyone say me how to make it possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without any backend stuff your only option is using a mailto in an href. This relies on the user sending the email themselves. You might be able to do something with javascript to populated the email .e.g

```
"mailto:"+emailTo+"&subject="+subjectText+"&body="+bodyText
```

Comment: This will require the user to have their default mail client setup. So if they use something like Gmail then this won't be too useful.

Comment: Not useful? http://www.gmailusers.com/tools-mailto.htm (and GMail **does** have an imap interface too)

Comment: I don't think many people will have installed special mail handlers and I doubt many have setup Outlook/Thunderbird etc to use GMail via IMAP.

Comment: hi i tried with above " <a href="mailto " concept but it is throughing SMTP server failed message when i click the "send" of "outlook". Can we send the mail without opening the Mailer to client.
That is on clicking the "Submit" mail shld be sent directly. Is it possible using javascripts and HTML itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can send yourself the form data by using the following html:

```html
<form method="post" action="mailto:me@my.com?subject=Results">

    <label for="Name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="Name"><br />
    <label for="Email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="Email"><br />
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Clicking on submit will create a new email message with the default mail client and will populate the subject `Results` and the body with the form data which will look like this

```
Name=PJP&Email=me%40my.com
```

Note how the data has been [url encoded](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm). e.g. `%40` for the `@` sign.

The user will have to press Send to send the message.

I used to do something similar to this around 15 years ago before I discovered a cgi-bin sendMail script on my old webhost.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't use server-side code? This kind of thing is very easily doable with PHP. Otherwise, the only choice is the `<a href="mailto` .. as pointed out already.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use PHP, you can use the formmail.cgi if your host provides one. Most hosts support this, and [instructions for using FormMail](http://www.scriptarchive.com/formmail.html) are simple.

This is trivial if you are using PHP though. You can try to rename the page with a .php extension (instead of .htm or .html) and put the following code into your page:

```
        <div class="post">
        <h2 class="title">Write to us</h2>
        <?php
        function validEmail($email)
        {
            $isValid = true;
            $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
            if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
            {
                $isValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
                $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
                $localLen = strlen($local);
                $domainLen = strlen($domain);
                if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
                {
                    // local part length exceeded
                    $isValid = false;
                }
                else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
                {
                    // domain part length exceeded
                    $isValid = false;
                }
                else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
                {
                    // local part starts or ends with '.'
                    $isValid = false;
                }
                else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
                {
                    // local part has two consecutive dots
                    $isValid = false;
                }
                else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
                {
                    // character not valid in domain part
                    $isValid = false;
                }
                else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
                {
                    // domain part has two consecutive dots
                    $isValid = false;
                }
                else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                            str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
                {
                    // character not valid in local part unless 
                    // local part is quoted
                    if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
                        str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
                    {
                    $isValid = false;
                    }
                }
                if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
                {
                    // domain not found in DNS
                    $isValid = false;
                }
            }
            return $isValid;
        }


        if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
          {//if "email" is filled out, proceed

          //check if the email address is invalid
          $mailcheck = validEmail($_REQUEST['email']);
          if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
            {
            echo "<p>Invalid e-mail address.</p>";
            }
          else {
            //send email
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
            mail("recepient@example.com", "Subject: Message from contact form",
            $message, 'From: "' . $name . '" <' . $email . '>' );
            echo "<p>Thank you for writing to our website. Please allow up to 24 hours for a reply, if you have requested one.</p>";
            }
          }
        else {
          //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
          echo "<form method='post' action='contact.php'>
          Name: <input id='name' name='name' type='text' /><br />
          E-mail: <input id='email' name='email' type='text' /> (required)<br />
          Message for us:<br />
          <textarea id='message' name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
          </textarea><br />
          <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Send Message' />
          </form>";
          }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi Pranab i m not familiar with PHP, and even CGI , so can u give me detailed descrption of how to use it.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can change the extension of your file from .htm (or .html) to .php, and then insert the above code into your page, and upload your page. This way should work on most hosts. If it doesn't, get back with any error message displayed so someone can help you. By the way, you should visit some of your other questions and accept the answer you find suitable, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Refer - https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782

You can Send an email using only JavaScript. No server-side languages involved.

Comment: Include links in comments.