# Send mail from HTML page not asp page

Tags: html, css, email

I have an HTML page that I am trying to use to send mail. But it is not working properly.

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: well the sending of email happen in the back end. how about you start by adding an email input field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to Send Email from HTML pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818962/need-to-send-email-from-html-pages)

Comment: As an alternative, you could use a service like wufoo.com and embed the form in your HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

SHORT ANSWER : NOT AT ALL POSSIBLE.....Even Bill Gates can't do that

Learn Server Side Programming if you want to send e-mails, HTML is just a markup...

- [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)
- [ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages)

Comment: do you have php script for this?

Comment: @user1830210 Why just pick up a script and use? What If I made a script, you send emails and I get a CC of those? Better learn it yourself and program it... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

HTML can't send mail. You need some sort of server side language to accomplish this (PHP, CGI, ASP, etc.) Otherwise, you can always use `<a href="mailto:...">Send an e-mail</a>`

Answer (score -1):

`HTML` is client side script. How could you send mail from client side??

Check this [link](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHP_mail%28%29) if you go with `PHP`.

Comment: Actually, you did "HTML is client side script"